# Creating a reverse grade calculator

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to create a reverse grade calculator. The basis of the idea is this:

1) You input what you want your final score to be (e.g., 93%)
2) You input the weight of each category (tests, assignments, etc.)
3) For every test/assignment it shows me what I need to get to attain or maintain a 93 average

So if tests are 60%, assignments are 25% and participation is 15% how would this work out?
What is the math behind doing this?

Comment: Well obviously one possibility is that you score $93$% for each component.  If you want one definite answer, you will have to supply more information.  Or you could forget about trying to second-guess the assessors and spend your time improving your grade by studying the subject instead ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your final grade is a weighted average between your marks for tests, assignments, and participation (each of these have a maximum of 100%)
Let $t$ be your test mark, $a$ be your assignments mark, $p$ be your participation mark. Then:
 $$0.60t + 0.25a + 0.15p = 0.93$$

If you knew two of the three marks, you could figure out what you needed in the third mark uniquely. Otherwise there would be multiple solutions to this problem. One example is $t,a,p$ all being 0.93.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I knew that was one way of doing it, but for multiple tests/assignments would it work out the same way? Would I always use that formula regardless of how many tests I have taken

Comment: $t$ is your average mark for all tests, it doesn't matter how many there are. How that average is calculated is up to your teacher. They might weigh them equally, or perhaps give more weight to later tests. :P

Comment: @eigenchris, welcome to math.se!  Like the icon ;-)

Comment: @eigenchris Alright thanks for everything man!

Comment: @David Thanks. I like linear algebra, as you might have guessed.